# What's a better way to differentiate row types on wide tables

Tags: tables, dashboard

Looking to improve the usability of the a claims dashboard for claims assessors. The users feedback was that they find it hard to visually differentiate each claim by panel type (row 1). i've fixed this by making the panel type a coloured tag (there are either panel or non panel claims).

this works until the user needs to scroll horizontally, as this is a wide table.

few options considered was

- making the whole row coloured based on panel type. However that would make the table visually too noisy.
- making the panel type sticky on the left. however we aleady have made the status column sticky.

Is there any other way to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solutions you've provided are the usual go-tos and seem good.

I'm usually a fan of unified solutions, so if you're already using sticky columns, maybe you should go for that, and stick both status and the type. They also don't have to be to the left **and** to the right - why not make them both to the right **or** both to the left?

I sometimes also use another one: you could set, for example, left border of the table the type's color and leave it always visible, even when scrolled. That way you get visual identification that's not too noisy and doesn't take up too much space. Something like this:

[image: Author's image updated to have colored borders]

You also seem to have an icon assigned to every type - that could be used the similar way to save space when scrolling.

Don't forget that color alone should never be the only mean of showing information - there should always be a way to decypher the color for the user.

Comment: Great answer. @BlueOcean could also highlight the row with a muted version of the panel type colour on hover.